# How can I search a range of multiple rows and columns for a value and return it's header?

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I would like to create an excel function that allows me to return a header for a row of data that contains a search value.

In the example attached, I'd like to be able to return which group each person is in, based on the table to the right containing the group lists.

It only needs to return the header for the first instance it finds.

[image: Example of how the data is organized]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

[image]

---

```
=@TOCOL(IFS(B2=F$2:I$4,E$2:E$4),2)
```

---

Or, Using one single formula:

```
=MAP(B2:B6,LAMBDA(α, @TOCOL(IFS(α=F2:I4,E2:E4),2)))
```

---

For Older Versions one could use the following:

[image]

---

```
="Group "&AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(E$2:E$4)-ROW(E$2)+1)/(B2=F$2:I$4),1)
```

---

Or,

```
=INDEX(E$2:E$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(E$2:E$4)-ROW(E$2)+1)/(B2=F$2:I$4),1))
```

---

Another option without `TOCOL()` to spill using `MAP()`

[image]

---

```
=MAP(B2:B6,LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(INDEX(E2:E4,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEQUENCE(ROWS(E2:E4))/(x=F2:I4),1)),"")))
```

---

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the TOCOL function in my version of excel.